# What is the expected value of sample variance in this problem?

Tags: self-study, variance, expected-value

> Let $x_1,x_2,..x_{21}$ be a random sample from a distribution having   variance 5. Let $$\bar X = \frac1{21}\sum_{i=1}^{21}X_i\quad\text{and}\quad
> S=\frac1{21}\sum_{i=1}^{21}(X_i-\bar X)^2$$ What is the value of $E(S)$
>   ?

I am unable to get why $\bar X$ is given and how to take expectation of $S$. After squaring and taking expectation of each term?

Comment: you are asked to compute standard deviance. You may find some hints here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3931/intuitive-explanation-for-dividing-by-n-1-when-calculating-standard-deviation

Comment: @Yurii I have read complete post refered by you , hints are not useful to me for this question .

Comment: $\bar X$ is not given but simply defined. Have you tried the decomposition$$S=\frac1{21}\sum_{i=1}^{21}X_i^2-\bar X^2$$before computing the expectation?

Comment: It is [well known](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3931) that $(21/20) S$ is an unbiased estimator of $5$.  Because expectation is linear, $S$ must be an unbiased estimator of $5\times 20/21$.