# Why Standard deviation formula has n-1 in the denominator but Variance only n?

Tags: variance, standard-deviation

If is true that SQRT(Variance) = SD then one cannot have n-1 in the denominator and the other not but should be same?

SD formula:

[image]

Variance formula:

[image]

Comment: These are two different concepts. The first formula refers to the **sample** standard deviation $S$, and you are correct that the sample variance is simply $S^2$. The second quantity refers to the population variance, which is more generally written as $$\sigma^2 = E\left[(X-\mu)^2\right].$$ An important distinction is that the population mean $\mu$ is *unknown* in the first case and must be estimated with $\bar X$, while in the second case $\mu$ is *known*.

Comment: @knrumsey-ReinstateMonica aha that is very interesting. and why is it -1 in sample case afterall and not same like in case of population? so population is the case if it is finite and whole set of numbers and sample if it is only part of it.

Comment: The estimated mean  is chosen such that it minimizes the mse. therefore using 1/n will lead to a biased estimate (meaning it will tend to be smaller than the actual population variance)

Comment: @luky, there are several excellent answers to that question (in your comment) in both of the linked questions above.

Comment: @Sebastian ok but if i have 1,2,3 population then SD 0.66 is actually smaller than actual SD? which would be 1 in case of sample?

Comment: Do you mean your obtained sample is 1,2,3?

Comment: @Sebastian no, that population is 1,2,3. then mean is 2, SD of population is 0.66 but SD of sample (if i worked with it as with sample) is 1 which seems to be more correct?

Comment: I think you should just check out those other posts that contain great explanations

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel%27s_correction

Answer (score 3):

Using $n-1$ as denominator instead of $n$ is called  'Bessel's correction' and it is used to reduce bias in the estimation of variance and standard deviation of the population.

If the sample variance is computed with $n$ as denominator, the sample variance is a biased estimator of the population variance.

As you correctly said, it is coherent to use the same denominator in computing the sample variance and the sample standard error.

Comment: You mean -1 in sample and and N in the population. But if i have eg 1,2,3 POPULATION then it make sense that SD is 2/2 = 1 because 2 is mean, so SD 1 is kind of correct SD, but if i compute it like population not sample then i do 2/3 = 0.66 SD which is not so much correct.

Comment: Look at the answer to this question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3931/intuitive-explanation-for-dividing-by-n-1-when-calculating-standard-deviation. I think it explains well what you have unclear

Comment: If 1,2,3 is a sample you actually do not know what is the mean value of the population. For this reason you prefer to overestimate the population variance and standard deviation using $n-1$.