# variance of a vector in Python numpy

Tags: python, variance, covariance

I want to calculate the variance of vector [0, 3, 4] in Python numpy. My code is

```
test=np.array([0, 3, 4])
print('test var', test.var(axis=0))
```

The output is

```
test var 2.8888888888888893.
```

Why? I thought it should be  4.333333333333334.

The cov function yields the correct result:

```
print("Covariance matrix of test:\n", np.cov(test))
```

Output

```
Covariance matrix of test:
 4.333333333333334
```

On the other hand , if I have a 2-dimensional array like this

```
k1=0.1
N=100
x1=np.random.rand(N)
nor=np.random.normal(0,0.5,size=N)
x3=k1*nor+(1-k1)*x1
X=np.vstack((x1,x3)).T
print('X var', X.var(axis=0))
C = np.cov(X.T)
c00 = C[0, 0]
c11 = C[1, 1]
print('c00 ', c00)
print('c11 ', c11)
```

Output

```
X var [0.0861854  0.06790817]
c00  0.0870559565349231
c11  0.06859411169279941
```

Here the var gives the same result as is in the diagonal of C. But with the vector it is not the same. What's going on here ?

Comment: $2.8888/4.3333 = 2/3$ demonstrates your question is answered at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3931.

Answer (score 2):

For the vector case, try the following code and you may want to read some documentations.

```
test=np.array([0, 3, 4])
print('test var', test.var(axis=0))
print('test var', test.var(axis=0, ddof=1)) # Note ddof=1 here
print("Covariance matrix of test:\n", np.cov(test))
```

doc for [np.var](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.var.html): checkout `ddof`

doc for [np.cov](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.cov.html): checkout `bias`, `ddof`

For the 2D case, they are not the same result, check all the digits :)

Comment: It’s worth mentioning that ddof=0 is population variance while ddof=1 is the sample variance.

Comment: @Tim Isn't it the other way around?

Comment: @Suvi yes, corrected it.

Comment: @Raymond Kwok, Thank you. I understood the 1-dimensional case. But about the 2-dimensional: why they are so close but not exactly the same? I tried ddof=1 here too but they still aren't the same.

Comment: Your 2D case computes variance for N=100 elements, so the numerical effect of setting ddof from 0 to 1 is much smaller than when you are computing variance for N=3 elements as in your vector case. remember it's about dividing the sum of squared difference from mean by (N-ddof), so for example ${xxx} \over {100}$ wouldn't be as different from ${xxx} \over {100-1}$ then ${xxx} \over {3}$ from ${xxx} \over {3-1}$

Comment: @Raymond Kwok Ok, but why I can't get the same result with cov() and var(), no matter whether I use ddof=1 or not? In the 1-dimensional case I at least was able to get the same result when I used ddof=1.