# Notation for distributions on subspaces

Tags: multivariate-normal-distribution, notation, bessels-correction

#### Question

What notation should I use for a normal distribution on a subspace $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$?

#### Motivation

I have a geometric intuition for Bessel's correction which goes something like this:

1. A random sample $x_1, x_2, x_3, \dots x_n$ of real numbers which are all drawn independently from $\mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$ is equivalent to drawing a single vector sample $\vec{x}$ from $X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu \vec{1}, \sigma^2 I_n)$.
2. We get an unbiased estimator $\hat{\mu} = \frac{\vec{x} \cdot \vec{1}}{n} = \bar{x} \vec{1}$ by projecting $\vec{x}$ onto the span of $\vec{1}$.  We cannot estimate $\sigma^2$ from this projection because we do not know the population mean $\mu$.
3. Let $S = \operatorname{Span}(\vec{1})^\perp$.  The projection of $X$ onto $\operatorname{Span}(\vec{1})^\perp$ will be normally distributed with mean $\vec{0}$ and covariance $\sigma^2 I_S$.  Since this has a known mean $\vec{0}$ we obtain an unbiased estimate $\hat{\sigma} = \frac{|\vec{x} - \bar{x}\vec{1}|}{n-1}$.

I have a bunch of pretty pictures I would like to draw to go along with this, but hopefully the geometric content is clear without them.

When trying to write this up I run into my question:  what notation is used for the normal distribution on a subspace?  I am tempted to write something like $\mathcal{N}(\vec{0}, \sigma^2 UU^\top)$ where the columns of $U$ form an orthogonal basis of the subspace.  This is not quite right, however, as applying the definition "verbatim" we would need to divide by the determinant of the singular matrix $UU^\top$

Comment: $\textrm{SN}(U)$ is sometimes used for the standard normal distribution on a vector space $U$.